# Rails: callback in controller to change attribute from true to false in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so I'm testing how to make a multiplayer Tic Tac Toe game, and for this I made a User model and a Game model, and by a has_many_through association they have various game_users.

Each game has an attribute: "seeking_players", that by default is true. When I create a new game_user, I check if they're exists a game with the seeking_players attribute set to true. If such a game exists, I make a new game_user for this game and I want to set this attribute to false.

But whatever I try, I can't seem to change this attribute. So, my question: what's wrong with this code: EDIT: this is the new working code after suggestions from @Малъ Скрылевъ

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_action :assign_game, only: [:new]

  def new
    @game.game_users.create(user: current_user)
    update_seeking_players
    redirect_to game_url(id: @game.id)
  end

  def game
    @game = Game.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def assign_game
    @game = Game.find_by_seeking_players(true) || Game.create
  end

  def update_seeking_players
    if @game.users.size == 2
      @game.update_attributes(seeking_players: false)
    end
  end

end
```

PS: I also tried changing this "seeking players" attribute in the Game model (with a callback "after_add"), which is maybe a more appropriate place? But I really can't figure out how to do this...

UPDATE:

these are the Game & GameUser model

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :game_users
    has_many :users, :through => :game_users

end

class GameUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :game
    belongs_to :user
    validates :game_id, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true

end
```

UPDATE 2 the migration for seeking_players

```
class AddSeekingPlayersWithIndexToGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :games, :seeking_players, :boolean, :default => true
    add_index :games, :seeking_players
  end
end
```

Comment: `@game.seeking_players = false` gere is you just change attribute, but the record isn';t yet updated, so replace with `@game.update(seeking_players: false)`

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't work

Comment: how does it look like?

Comment: replace `only: [:gameRequest]`, with real action name like `new` etc

Comment: please dont put any data in comments, update the post instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some issues with the contoller.

1. It seems that `gameRequest` isn't real action name like `new`, so replace it with real one.
2. Try not using camel case (or similar) in names of variables and method, since it descreace understability of the code.

So I propose you to change the contoller as follows:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :logged_in_user
   before_action :assign_game, only: [:new]

   def new
      @game.game_users.create(user: current_user)
      update_seeking_players

      redirect_to game_url(@game)
   end

   def game
   end

   private

   def assign_game
      @game = Game.find_by_seeking_players(true) || Game.create
   end

   def update_seeking_players
      if @game.users.size == 2
         @game.update(seeking_players: false)
      end
   end

end
```

so and if `seeking_players` is a real column, and it must be, so remove `attr_accessor`, since it block access to db column:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :game_users
   has_many :users, :through => :game_users
end
```

Comment: @FlipVermeersch add `pry` gem, put `binding.pry` at the end of `pdate_seeking_players` and see `@game` in the context.

Comment: @FlipVermeersch well, wheither is `seeking_players` a column of games table or not?

Comment: @FlipVermeersch I meant column of table in db yes?

Comment: ok it works now!! Thanks alot for your help, wouldn't have found it without you (found it with the pry gem). What happened was: after the 'redirect_to game_url(@game)', the '@game' became '@game.id' (don't know why exactly), so when i put the 'update_seeking_players' before the redirect (as a 'after_action' to 'assign_game') it magically started working. Thanks alot for all the little mistakes you took out!